# Python - Replace NA's on Joins not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill the values of a NA with some default text values.

Here is my df1

```
data = [['Alex','10'],['Bob','12'],['Clarke','13']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id','Age'])
```

Here is my df2

```
data = [['Alex','10'],['Clarke','13']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id','Age'])
```

Here is my df3

```
data = [['Alex','10']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id','Age'])
```

Here is my output as per this code

```
df4 = (pd.concat([df2.set_index('Id'), df3.set_index('Id')], axis=1).reindex(df1.Id, fill_value='IDNP').reset_index())
```

All the Id's in df1 needs to be present in df4.

If an Id is not present in df2 or df3 then it gets replaced by 'IDNP'.

This is my output as per my code,

```
       Id   Age   Age
0    Alex    10    10
1     Bob  IDNP  IDNP
2  Clarke    13   NaN
```

What I want,

```
       Id   Age   Age
0    Alex    10    10
1     Bob  IDNP  IDNP
2  Clarke    13   IDNP
```

Where am I going wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need replace all missing values after `concat` by list of `DataFrame` with creating index by `Id` use:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df4 = pd.concat([x.set_index('Id') for x in dfs], axis=1).fillna('IDNP')
print (df4)
       Age   Age   Age
Alex    10    10    10
Bob     12  IDNP  IDNP
Clarke  13    13  IDNP
```

Your solution create mising value, because it return pd.concat:

```
print ((pd.concat([df2.set_index('Id'), df3.set_index('Id')], axis=1)))
       Age  Age
Alex    10   10
Clarke  13  NaN
```

So it is not replace by `fill_value` parameter.

Possible solution is call `fillna`:

```
df4 = (pd.concat([df2.set_index('Id'), df3.set_index('Id')], axis=1)
         .fillna('IDNP')
         .reindex(df1.Id, fill_value='IDNP')
         .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex by `df1.Id` before concatenating:

```
df4 = pd.concat([df2.set_index('Id').reindex(df1.Id, fill_value='IDNP'),
                 df3.set_index('Id').reindex(df1.Id, fill_value='IDNP')], axis=1).reset_index()

print(df4)
```

**Output**

```
       Id   Age   Age
0    Alex    10    10
1     Bob  IDNP  IDNP
2  Clarke    13  IDNP
```